Can't type anything on chromium (snap)
I accidentally removed my dotfiles from my $HOME directory (which includes the .config/chromium directory and then moved then backed there and now I cannot type anything in chromium. I removed and reinstalled it and looked at the following question but that did not solve the problem:
Unable to type anything on Chromium
Here are my system specifications

Chromium 129.0.6668.89 snap
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
DE: GNOME 42.9

